(GoogleHome app) If you press '+' or '-' on the 'thermostat control screen' to adjust the temperature, the temperature is not adjusted by 1 degree
I'm developing a thermostat in the Google Home app (node.js). (using iphone15).The temperature is currently moving only 0.5 degrees Celsius. I want to make it move 1 degree. I looked at Google's help, but it didn't help. Is it not functional?
I made a video of the current (iphone)Google Home app thermostat, which is only 0.5 degrees and not 1 degree each.  I want to control the temperature by 1 degree each.
https://youtube.com/shorts/c-lUAAeBti8?si=LeaQqdC8sU0QZJq5
Data[abcd][defg] = {
    properties: {
      id: id,
      type: "action.devices.types.THERMOSTAT",
      traits: [
        "action.devices.traits.OnOff",
        "action.devices.traits.TemperatureControl",
        "action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting"
      ],

     ......

     attributes: {
        temperatureRange: {
          minThresholdCelsius: Math.round(Number(JSON.parse(deviceNonPase).minValue)),
          maxThresholdCelsius: Math.round(Number(JSON.parse(deviceNonPase).maxValue)), 
        },

        temperatureStepCelsius: 1, //////////// Here!!! 1 but not 0.5
            
        temperatureUnitForUX: "C",
        temperatureSetpointCelsius: Number(JSON.parse(deviceNonPase).heat),    
        temperatureAmbientCelsius: Number(JSON.parse(deviceNonPase).currenTemp), 
     

        thermostatTemperatureRange: {
        ... .
        },

        thermostatTemperatureUnit: "C",

        availableThermostatModes: [
          "off", 
          "heat", 
          "on",
          ....
        ],

      },

     ........



Thanks for sharing this. I can reproduce the issue on my end using Google Home Playground. Can you please open a ticket in public issue tracker and share the full Sync Response as well. I will follow up with internal teams for further debugging. Please paste your ticket link in the comment.

Is this what you want?
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/371237541
thank you

received, thanks

Dear @Armen Sarkisyan
Thank you for your time and assistance.
May I know the current situation for the above mentioned issue?
My app controls the temperature in 1 degree units, but Google Home app sets it to 0.5 degree units even if it's currently set to 1 degree units.
May I know how this is going... or if it's possible or not to solve it?
Once again, thank you for your time and attention.
